# Combining two dataframes and retaining latest values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and struggling get a solution for the following problem. I have two data frames, let's say `current_df` and `old_df`. The columns of both the data frames are common but the length may vary. To explain the problem in further detail lets assume the columns to be - `Name, Id, Salary, Work_hours, Location, Date_updated`. When both of data frames combine, based on the `Date_updated`(it is a datetime object),

1. if the `Date_updated` of the `current_df` is latest compared to `old_df`, then update the values of `Salary, Work_hours, Location, Date_updated` to the ones corresponding to `new_df`.
2. if any new Employee record is present in the `new_df` then just add it as it is in the resultant data frame.
3. if there is no change in the other parameters then update only the time updated

I tried something like this

```
merged_df=new_df.set_index('Id').combine_first(old_df.set_index('Id')).reset_index()    
old_df = merged_df    
new_df = my_func()    
#my_func() returns a data frame
```

But it produces inconsistent result(I am dumping the old_df in a pickle file and later loading it to  to update to latest values by comparing it with new_df, but when i do so, too many duplicate values are created at once and dataframe size increases by factor of 10 for every subsequent run.). I would be very grateful if anyone suggest an alternative approach other than `combine_first` to tackle the issue.
Thank you.

Comment: If you have many rows for the same index, then this can result in multiple rows. To avoid that you can use `drop_duplicates(subset="Id")` on each of the dataframes' before `combine_first`.

Comment: Is the `Id` a unique identifier of an employee?

Comment: @Filip yes it is.

Comment: @pravashpanigrahi the duplication issue happens especially when i load the `old_df` from disk (pkl file) after a long time

Comment: SO the reason might be the `index value (Id)` value in the `old_df` must have changed. that's the reason it's failing to match the rows correctly. In that case for both dfs, you need to reset -`reset_index(inplace=True)` and then set -`set_index('Id', inplace=True)`. Then you can use `old_df.update(new_df)`

Comment: @pravashpanigrahi the `.update()` method fails in this case. if `new_df` doesn't have values which is in `old_df`, then in such cases the `updated_df` will be missing such values and thats not desired output.

Comment: Oh ok. First try with passing a parameter to update() - `old_df.update(new_df, overwrite=False)`. Otherwise, use merge - `old_df.merge(new_df, on="Id", how="left")`. And then you can fill the missing values with original - `updated_df['Id'] = updated_df['Id_y'].fillna(updated_df['Id_x'])`. Then drop the redundant column - `updated_df.drop(['Id_x', 'Id_y'], axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are explaining:

```py
def get_updated_df(old_df: pd.DataFrame, new_df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.concat([old_df, new_df])
    
    if not all(df.groupby('Id').nunique().Name == 1):
        raise ValueError('An employee has changed Id or Name, or the same Id has been assigned to two different employees.')

    if 'Id' in old_df.columns:
        old_df = old_df.set_index('Id')
    if 'Id' in new_df.columns:
        new_df = new_df.set_index('Id')
    
    return (
        df
        .sort_values('Date_updated')
        .groupby(['Name', 'Id'])
        .last()
        .reset_index()
        .set_index('Id')
        .sort_index()
    )
```

---

*`.sort_values('Date_updated')` is only needed if the date for an employee in the old data could be more recent than the date for the same employee in the new data. If this is not possible, then you can remove this line.*

*This works also if `Date_updated` is a `datetime` object.*

---

Here is some sample data to try with:

```py
columns = ['Name', 'Id', 'Salary', 'Work_hours', 'Location', 'Date_updated']

old_data = [
    ['John', 1, 1000, 100, 'York', '2013-01-01'],
    ['Tim', 2, 1500, 210, 'Chicago', '2013-04-03'],
    ['Rob', 3, 900, 180, 'San Francisco', '2013-02-07'],
    ['Tom', 4, 2000, 220, 'New York', '2013-01-01'],
    ['Steve', 5, 1200, 190, 'Chicago', '2013-06-01'],
    ['Jim', 6, 1000, 170, 'New York', '2013-01-01'],
    ['Mark', 7, 1500, 210, 'Chicago', '2013-04-03'],
    ['John', 8, 900, 180, 'San Francisco', '2013-02-07'],
]


new_data = [
    ['John', 1, 2000, 200, 'New York', '2014-01-01'],
    ['Tim', 2, 1000, 300, 'Miami', '2014-04-03'],
    ['Rob', 9, 900, 180, 'San Francisco', '2016-02-07'],  # new employee
]


df_old = pd.DataFrame(data=old_data, columns=columns).set_index('Id').sort_index()

df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=new_data, columns=columns).set_index('Id').sort_index()

updated_df = get_updated_df(df_old, df_new)
```

*`.sort_index()` is not really needed, it is just sorting the DataFrame by the index (Id) to make it visually easier to verify the results.*

---

*John moved some time in the year of 2014 from `York` to `New York`, got an 100% increase in salary, and 100% increase in work hours.*

*Tim moved some time in the year of 2013, between April and December, from `Chicago` to `Miami`, got a 33% decrease in salary, and 43% increase in work hours.*

*A new employee, Rob, was hired in 2016 to work for the `San Francisco` office.*

Comment: What if  there are new values in `new_data`, will it still work?

Comment: @MoneetDevadiga
Yes, since `.last()` will give you the last entry, and if there is only one, that one is also the last. I have adjusted the sample data to reflect this.